# Mouse Wheel Problem on Mac when opening my Website

Tags: html, css, macos, scroll, mousewheel

I built a website, and the designer who drew the design of the page has Mac computer. He says that Mouse wheel scrolling doesn't work, only the browsers left "slider" works. I mean when you are with your mouse in center of the screen and you do the mouse wheel scroll, the page doesn't move, and if you drag Browsers scroll - it moves.

The thing is that I've been only using PC so I've got no idea - why that can happen with a website on Mac. It works fine in 5 browsers (IE, Opera, FF, Chrome and Safari  on PC), and mouse scroll has problem in any browser on Mac.

Can anyone share with your ideas why could that happen and maybe how to fix it. I have 0% experience with Mac, I don't even know what to do after turn on/off button :)

P.S. i tagged PHP, CSS and HTML because the website is developed using those languages and Flash player & slider.

---

www.ninogvetadze.com/new

Comment: its hard to know what the problem is without seeing the site. please provide some code/links.

Comment: @Jared, they have touch scrolling functionality. And @Mikey, MAC is not an acronym. It makes my eyes bleed every time I see it capitalized.

Comment: There is no way to help without the actual code to review.

Comment: @Josh - I realized that, it's why I deleted it before your comment. ;)

Comment: Tell your designer to disable the style-sheets of the page. And then he should report back if the mousewheel still does not work.

Comment: the older mighty mouse have little scroll balls that are notorious for getting stuck... i didn't see the deleted comment, but I presume it was something along these lines. are you sure it is a magic mouse or trackpad that is being used?

Comment: @Dave - It was just my mistake. It's been a while since I was a Mac user, so I was thinking more about the old school mouse that didn't have a physical wheel. I don't even know what they have nowadays.

Comment: Macs have whatever kind of USB mouse the user plugs in... :-)

Comment: @Josh Einstein  -  Well i'm not a MAC user so I will write Mac or MAC :D

Comment: Thanks Mates, I'll do everything that you wrote here... well here's the link:  www.ninogvetadze.com/new

Comment: @Mikey - Grow up. You don't have to use one to spell it correctly. A MAC is a Media Access Controller, not a Macintosh.

Answer (score 0):

Before you go ahead and deem it a code problem, I'd have your mac user clean his scroll wheel out with either a.) an alcohol wipe or b.) a piece of paper. Rub the mouse ball with the wipe, or apply pressure to it with the paper and roll it back and forth to `git` any dirt out. I'm willing to bet it is a hardware issue rather than code.

If it is a newer mouse without the scroll ball, then... well, I lost the bet.

Answer (score 0):

> only the browsers left "slider" works

If it's on the left, it ain't the browser's standard scroll bar.

> mouse scroll has problem in any browser on Mac.

Because all those browsers are using the same Flash player plugin.

> the website is developed using those languages and Flash player & slider.

Yep. There you go - the Flash "slider" obviously wasn't tested on a Mac. Now you know why designers with a clue rely on standard-based approaches instead of Flash.

**(Edit)** Yep - just used the address in your comment above to look at your site. There's a "macmousewheelflash.js" being loaded, which apparently has something to do with adding mouse wheel support to the Flash movie at the top. Looks like that's interfering with proper wheel support for the rest of the page. You could probably just remove that - I don't see where the Flash movie needs to scroll anyway. Or, for that matter, why you need Flash for a simple cross-fade slide show...

Comment: Okay, but the answer stands. Your problem is the "Flash player & slider" you're using - it obviously doesn't work well on Macs. Scroll wheels, including those on standard USB mice & trackballs (I'm using a Logitech M570 right now) generally work just like they're supposed to.